# Hello, got bitcoin core and am confused

Tags: bitcoin-core

I recently got a new bitcoin wallet from bitcoin core and it is taking fort to sync, during the sync it gave me an address I sent bitcoin to however due to complications syncing, the address is no longer in my recieving addresses, will it still be saved with the wall.dat file with the bitcoin core files automatically? If not how do I add a custom address to s new wallet to receive the bitcoin if not
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All addresses Bitcoin Core generates will be permanently stored in your `wallet.dat`. It now depends on what your "complication" was. If you just pressed "receive" again and generated another address, you've got nothing to worry about, your money will show up once Bitcoin Core is fully synchronized.

If your "complication" included that you've removed Bitcoin Core in between and also deleted your `wallet.dat`, your money would probably be lost.

Comment: I set it to save to a 128gb micro SD with 100gb free, this for some reason didn't happen and while it was putting it on my hard drive it ran out of space so I had to set a datadir to the SD, now when I try to get the private key to sync the address to another account to check funds that were coming in by dumping the private key, it can't find it :L is there a way to recover it and if not will the funds be in my wallet when it syncs? Worried I've lost the bitcoin :L thanks

Comment: The wallet.Dat and files are still in the same place where they originally were on the sd, it just stopped because it tried to put the blocks on my hard drive and now the address is gone

Comment: The only reason I have any concerns is because I can't locate the private key or see the address any more, will this solve once synced

Comment: To recover your funds, the `wallet.dat` and your password are the only necessary pieces of data.